# Declaracion de variables Double en android studio con Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una duda respecto a la declaracioón de variables en android studio con `Kotlin`:

En `kotlin` la variable de tipo Double se declara de la siguiente forma:

```
   var origen: Double
```

Y utilizo ese valor de la siguiente forma en android studio:

```
 origen = location.latitude
```

El detalle es que android studio me dice que inicialize el valor de origen de esta forma:

```
var origen: Double = 0.0
```

Es correcto inicializar la variable como me pide android studio??. No interfiere en nada si uso esa variable con mis otras funciones?? por favor soy nuevo en android studio, ayudenme...

Comment: Hola Nik, en realidad no lo pide Android Studio, lo requiere el lenguaje Kotlin.

Comment: entonces al declarar una variable si o si tengo que inicializar?? esa era mi duda

Comment: así es, de otra forma no te permitiría construir el programa.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys ahora entendi... como podria comunicarme con usted para preguntarle si tengo dudas en kotlin?

Comment: Aquí puedes agregar tus preguntas y sería más fácil que yo o algún miembro de la comunidad para ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias... seguire programando entonces...

Comment: aquí estamos para ayudarnos todos en la comunidad, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es correcto y no interfiere en nada de hecho al parecer vas a usar la variable para almacenar valores de geolocalización.

Al declarar la variable como tipo `Double` (o `Float`) indicas que usaras una convención para números de punto flotante, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
 var origen: Double = 0
```

sería correcto si definieras la variable como tipo `Int`:

```
 var origen: Int = 0
```

Por lo tanto lo correcto para inicializar un valor `Double` debe ser:

```
 var origen: Double = 0.0
```

Revisa la información sobre los [Tipos básicos en Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html).